# ¿Cómo verificar si un array está contenido en otro array?

Tags: javascript

Tengo que verificar que lo que voy guardando dentro del acumulador este en una de las combinaciones posibles de un array de arrays.

Así probé de hacerlo, el acumulador va guardando los números que el usuario va seleccionando. Pero no me devuelve nada el for, a menos que ponga dentro del includes un numero entero como: acumulador.includes(1), no me verifica el array

```
const ganador = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]];
let acumulador = [];
let selector = 0;

if(selector === 0 && document.getElementById(id).classList.length === 1){
    document.getElementById(id).classList.add (jugador1.figura)
    selector = 1
    acumulador.push(parseInt(id))
    for(let i = 0; i < ganador.length; i++){
         if(acumulador.includes(ganador[i])){
              alert("felicidades" + jugador1.nombre)
    }
}
```

Comment: A mí sí me funciona la solución de Jaime.

Comment: @ffflabs se refería a una pregunta que le había hecho de su propio código porque no había especificado la pregunta en su publicación. Como editó, borré mi comentario.

Comment: ack, pero de la manera como quedó no se entiende nada. Es importante que todo el contenido acá generado le pueda servir a un visitante cualquiera que busque algo parecido al enunciado.

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que en `javascript` no puedes comparar de manera explícita un array con otro array (`array1 == array2`). Como los objetos son en realidad referencias a memoria y dos arrays diferentes tienen diferentes referencias (ya que se guardan en lugares diferentes) entonces  siempre dan `false`, incluso aunque tengan los mismos elementos. El operador `==` y `===` en objetos compara las referencias y la función `.include` internamente utiliza este operador, por eso no funciona tu código.

```js
let arr1 = [1]
let arr2 = [1]

console.log(`arr1 == arr2 da ${arr1 == arr2}`)
console.log(`arr1 === arr2 da ${arr1 === arr2}`)

console.log(`[1] == [1] da ${[1] == [1]}`)

console.log(`[[1,2], [1]].includes([1]) da ${[[1,2], [1]].includes([1])}`)
console.log(`[[1,2], [1]].includes([1,2]) da ${[[1,2], [1]].includes([1])}`)
```

Una de las solucionas más usadas para afrontar este problema es muy simple. Convierte los arrays que deseas comparar a cadena de texto con `JSON.stringify` y luego compara los valores de las cadenas. Esto te dirá si son o no son iguales. Ejemplo:

```js
let arr1 = [1]
let arr2 = [1]

console.log(`arr1 == arr2 da ${JSON.stringify(arr1) == JSON.stringify(arr2)}`)

console.log(`[1] == [1] da ${JSON.stringify([1]) == JSON.stringify([1])}`)
```

Basado en esta forma de comparar podemos construir una función que cheque si un array contiene otro array:

```js
// Busca si el array item está contenido en el array de arrays arr
function isArrayInArray(arr, item){
  let item_as_string = JSON.stringify(item);
 
  return arr.some(function(ele){
    return JSON.stringify(ele) === item_as_string;
  });
}

console.log(isArrayInArray([[1], [2]],[1]))
console.log(isArrayInArray([[1], [1, 2]],[1,2]))
```

Declarando esta última función, tu código podría solucionarse de la siguiente manera:

```
for(let i = 0; i < ganador.length; i++) {
    if(isArrayInArray(acumulador, ganador[i]) {
       alert("felicidades" + jugador1.nombre)
    }
}
```